# Android Dynamically Load ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, asp.net-web-api, android-scrollview

- I am adding item in ListView using ArrayAdapter.

  - First display 15 item  in the ListView.
  - Scroll to bottom it must fetch and display next 15 content from web API.

Give some idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tutorial of lazy loading with image. You should check that out

http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/loading-remote-images-in-a-listview-on-android/

Here is some demo of lazy listview from GitHub.

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Hope those can help !!

[Credit go to original author of code and tutorial]

Comment: This is something different. The example shows how to load images "lazy" with predefined elements. The Jeeva asked how to dynamically add elements to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 2):

set OnScrollListener. Check how much elements are visible, which is the first visible element.

```
@Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if(((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount) && (totalItemCount > 0)) {
                loadNewData();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I feel like I need to comment here not to undermine this answer but to warn people about the downside to using `onScroll`. I've been testing it as I need a mechanism that loads data dynamically, and one thing I've noticed is if a user flings the list too fast the code may never run. This of course is a problem. In my case I need to be able to dynamically load the list even when a user flings. If you just wanna load after the end or beginning of a list, then this answer is just fine. But would like to save people some time if they go this route and this limitation causes an issue :)

Answer (score 2):

`getView()` of the Adapter will be invoked when an item is visible.
So you can start the fetch and display next 15 when `getView(14, convertView, parent)`.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a time-consume task to load data from internet. So AsyncTask is implemented to handle the `ListView` the bitmap is also loaded in background thread which u can ignore and take the others, and `setListAdapter()` in `onPostExecute()`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AndroidList extends ListActivity {

     public class backgroundLoadListView extends   AsyncTask {

      @Override  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {   
// TODO Auto-generated method stub   
setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(AndroidList.this, R.layout.row, month));   Toast.makeText(AndroidList.this,     "onPostExecute n: setListAdapter after bitmap preloaded",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}

      @Override  protected void onPreExecute() {  
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
Toast.makeText(AndroidList.this,     "onPreExecute n: preload bitmap in AsyncTask",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}

      @Override  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
 preLoadSrcBitmap();   
return null;  
}

}

     String image_URL=  "http://androidboss.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/83e268b443ndroid.png.png";

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {  
Bitmap bm;

      public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,    String[] objects) 
{   
super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);  
 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

       bm = srcBitmap; 
  }

      @Override  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
//return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

       View row = convertView;

       if(row==null){    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();    row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);   
 }

       TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.weekofday);   label.setText(month[position]);   ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

       icon.setImageBitmap(bm);

       return row;  
 }
 }

     Bitmap srcBitmap; 
private void preLoadSrcBitmap()
{  
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
  bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
 bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1; 
 srcBitmap = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
 }

     String[] month = {   "January", "February", "March", "April",   "May", "June", "July", "August",   "September", "October", "November", "December"   };

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //setContentView(R.layout.main);

      /*setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,        R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, DayOfWeek));*/  new backgroundLoadListView().execute();
 }

     @Override protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
 {  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
//super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); 
 Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

     private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {     
   Bitmap bitmap = null;  
InputStream in = null;       
 try { 
  in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);  
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);   in.close(); 
  } catch (IOException e1)
 {  }

      return bitmap;                 }

     private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{  
InputStream inputStream = null;  
URL url = new URL(strURL);  
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

      try{
   HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;  
 httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");   
httpConn.connect();

       if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {   
 inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();   
  } 
   }  catch (Exception ex){  }

      return inputStream; }
}
```