# what layout does Google Play use?

Tags: android-layout, google-play, android-gridview

I use GridView to display image. When scroll to bottom of GridView, more image will load and display use notifydatasetChange().
But when notifydatasetChange() call, all image reload. I want only new image add to GridView load like Google Play.
In Google Play, when i scroll to bottom, new application icon,price,title will load and display without reload old application icon.
Is Google Play use GridView to display list of app?
Anyone know how to do like this?

Comment: duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661021/android-dynamically-load-listview

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679997/in-the-google-play-app-how-is-the-viewgroup-showing-the-application-top-lists-i , Google Play uses bucket adapter to show Grid Like list view.